# Need to change a key from greater than less than to backslash pipe

Tags: 12.04

I started a programming class and found i can't type in a backslash or a pipe because the corresponding key is mapped to a greater than less than symbol.

How do i change the key over when i can't use xev to determine it's behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out:

[Howto: Custom keyboard layout definitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Howto%3a%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions)

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of page i was looking for but could not find!

Answer (score 2):

are you sure the selected layout corresponds to your keyboard ??

> system -> preferences -> keyboard - layouts

Comment: I've checked and rechecked this, and it does the same thing on ALL of the acceptable layouts.